# Is $f(x)=\mu(x+A)$ measurable for a closed subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$, where $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is $f(x)=\mu(x+A)$ measurable for a closed subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$ where  $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R^n}$?

I tried to show f is continuous by representing f as an integral the characteristic function of the set ${x+A}$. If A is closed  interval, then somehow I deduced that f is continuous, but for general closed Borel set, I could not write down properly,

Any hint, way to solve and approach are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: The Dirac measure shows it doesn't have to be continuous.

Comment: Is dirac measure a Borel measure? I think, no it is not.

Comment: The Dirac measure $\delta_x(A) = I_{x\in A}$.  Clearly every Borel set is $\delta_x$ measurable.

Comment: You are right. Dirac measure you defined above is of course a Borel measure, I confused it with diract delta function from which you get Dirac measure. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function $h_n(y) = (1-n\,\text{dist}(y,A))^+$, where $\text{dist}(A,y) = \inf\{|z-y|:z\in A\}$.  Since $A$ is closed, it follows that $h_n \searrow I_A$ as $n \to \infty$.  Therefore $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int h_n(y-x) \, d\mu(y)$ by monotone convergence.  Since $h_n$ is uniformly continuous, we have that $x\mapsto \int h_n(y-x) \, d\mu(y)$ is continuous.  Therefore $f$ is a pointwise limit of continuous functions, and hence Borel measurable.

Comment: What is the meaning of "+" sign in the definition of $h_n$ you mean positive part of the fucntion $h_n(y)$. Also what is $f_n$? you mean h_n? thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, and yes.  I'll fix the latter one.